# Ms Access: DELETE query with JOIN and NOT EQUAL operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-delete

I'm writing a simple configurator in MS Access. There are two kind of rules, Mandatory and invalid. For the invalid rules I use this SQL, and it works fine:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW RuntimeBOM.*
FROM CurrentInvalid
INNER JOIN RuntimeBOM ON ([RuntimeBOM].[OPTION] = [CurrentInvalid].[Invalid option])
AND ([RuntimeBOM].[FEATURE] = [CurrentInvalid].[Invalid feature])
WHERE RuntimeBOM.SessionID=fOSUserName();
```

For the Mandatory rules I've tryed this one, but it does not affect any record in the table, indeed, it returns the runtime error "3086" (It's impossible to delete from the specified tables):

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW RuntimeBOM.*
FROM CurrentMandatory
INNER JOIN RuntimeBOM ON (RuntimeBOM.FEATURE = CurrentMandatory.MandatoryFeature)
AND (RuntimeBOM.OPTION <> CurrentMandatory.MandatoryOption)
WHERE RuntimeBOM.SessionID=fOSUserName();
```

fOSUserName() is a vba function to get the username of the computer where is running the application.

```
╔══════════════╗   ╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗   ╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║  RuntimeBOM  ║   ║              CurrentInvalid              ║   ║              CurrentMandatory              ║
╟───────┬──────╢   ╟────┬──────┬───────────────┬──────────────╢   ╟────┬──────┬────────────────┬───────────────╢
║FEATURE│OPTION║   ║Feat│Option│Invalid feature│Invalid option║   ║Feat│Option│MandatoryFeature│MandatoryOption║
╠═══════╪══════╣   ╠════╪══════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╣   ╠════╪══════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╣
║FT001  │OP001 ║   ║FTaa│OPaa  │FT001          │OP001         ║   ║FTaa│OPaa  │FT002           │OP008          ║
║FT001  │OP002 ║   ║FTaa│OPaa  │FT001          │OP002         ║   ╚════╧══════╧════════════════╧═══════════════╝
║FT001  │OP003 ║   ║FTaa│OPaa  │FT001          │OP004         ║
║FT001  │OP004 ║   ║FTaa│OPaa  │FT001          │OP005         ║
║FT001  │OP005 ║   ╚════╧══════╧═══════════════╧══════════════╝
║FT002  │OP006 ║
║FT002  │OP007 ║
║FT002  │OP008 ║
║FT002  │OP009 ║
║FT002  │OP010 ║
╚═══════╧══════╝
```

In this scenario imagine the user has selected "FTaa" and "OPaa" somewhere, and for this reason "CurreintINvalid" and "CurrentMandatory" are populated in this way. The SQL for the invalid rules, deletes the records inside RuntimeBOM where FEATURE is equal to FT001 and OPTION is equal to "OP001", "OP002", "OP004", "OP005" (as it's defined in "CurrentInvalid"). The SQL for the mandatory rules, deletes all the records inside RuntimeBOM where FEATURE is equal to FT002 and OPTION is not equal to "OP008" (as it's defined in "CurrentMandatory").
The expected results:

```
    ╔══════════════╗
    ║  RuntimeBOM  ║
    ╟───────┬──────╢
    ║FEATURE│OPTION║
    ╠═══════╪══════╣
    ║FT001  │OP003 ║
    ║FT002  │OP008 ║
    ╚═══════╧══════╝
```

Thank You!

Comment: Check the `SELECT` version of the problem `DELETE` query. Is it an update able query? Are those joined tables or queries themselves, specifically *CurrentMandatory*?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, They are table, the strange thing is that the first delete works fine. while the second no. if transform the second query into a SELECT it works.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are trying to delete a record, that is not unique, and/or one of your joins is aggregating data.

Run the query as a **Select Query**, and verify your results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've debugged starting from the SELECT version of the query. It has been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to the suggestions, I think I've found the solution.
It seems that the first "DELETE" works fine because inside the "JOIN" statement there are just "=" comparisons. in the second SQL I've left the "=" statement inside the "JOIN", while I've moved the "<>" statement inside the "WHERE":

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW RuntimeBOM.*
FROM CurrentMandatory INNER JOIN RuntimeBOM ON (RuntimeBOM.FEATURE)=[CurrentMandatory].[MandatoryFeature]
WHERE RuntimeBOM.SessionID=fOSUserName() And ((RuntimeBOM.OPTION)<>CurrentMandatory.MandatoryOption);
```

Thanks.